# Changing DataGridView Header Cells' Text Alignment And The Font Size

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to change the text alignment and the font size of a DataGridView. All the Columns are created programatically at runtime. Here's the code..

```
private void LoadData()
{
    dgvBreakDowns.ColumnCount = 5;
    dgvBreakDowns.Columns[0].Name = "Breakdown No";
    dgvBreakDowns.Columns[1].Name = "Breakdown Type";
    dgvBreakDowns.Columns[2].Name = "Machine Type";
    dgvBreakDowns.Columns[3].Name = "Date";
    dgvBreakDowns.Columns[4].Name = "Completed";

    dgvBreakDowns.Columns[4].Visible = false;

    foreach (DataGridViewHeaderCell header in dgvBreakDowns.Rows)
    {
        header.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        header.Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
}
```

This `LoadData()` method is called in the Form's constructor. The Columns are created but their Headers' changes don't apply. 
I think its because of a flaw in my loop `foreach (DataGridViewHeaderCell header in dgvBreakDowns.Rows)?` I'm not sure. I tried changing it to `dgvBreakDowns.Columns` and I get an InvalidCastException. How can I select the Header Cells to apply those changes?

I have another minor issue. When I run the program it looks like this.

[image]

Notice the first Cell is selected by default therefore it appears Blue. Sure it doesn't affect anything but it just looks somewhat ugly and untidy. It is possible to stop it from selecting the Cell like that?

Comment: That's odd that you can unbox a `DataGridViewRow` to a `DataGridViewHeaderCell` like that. I think the only reason your code works is the `Rows` collection is empty...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this (note I'm using Columns here and not Rows):

```
foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dgvBreakDowns.Columns)
{
    col.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    col.HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

As for deselecting the cell, try [`dgvBreakDowns.ClearSelection()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxdf3ekh.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much but I need for DataGrid and I've changed your code to [This](https://pastebin.com/GPSaAK4m) , This code for change to DataGrid columnd header. I hope helps to others...

Comment: Ahhh this helped me come to this for my code: C.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = C.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment;

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The Align property is completely ignored!

Answer (score 7):

or just try this:

```
dgvBreakDowns.Columns[4].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment` with `MiddleCenter` as its value. Check the code below:

```
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for reference; there are some things to take into consideration in order for the control to show the customized Styles correctly.
In this situation regarding Column Headers; but these do apply to further customization:

- Set: "dataGridView.EnableHeadersVisualStyles" to false.
- Apply styles after the DatagridView is Visible.
- To align Header Columns; the "*AutoSizeColumnMode*" must be Set to Fill.

To ensure that all the customized Styles are applied after the Control is Visible; you can use the "*DataGridView_VisibleChanged*" Event.

**DataGridView Visible Changed Event**

```
/// <summary> Occurrs whenever the Control gets visible. </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void DataGridView_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView.Visible)
    {
        DataGridView_AutoSizeColumn();
        DataGridView_CentreHeaders();
        // Etc...
    }
}
```

**Header Columns AutoSizeMode**

```
private void DataGridView_AutoSize()
{
   var col = dataGridView.Columns;

   for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)
   {
      if (i == 0) { col[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill; }
      if (i == 1) { col[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill; }
      // Etc...
    }
}
```

**Centre Header Columns Text and Set Font**

```
/// <summary> Centre Columns Headers. </summary>
private void DataGridView_CentreHeaders()
{
    // Centre Column Cells Content
    dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;

    // Centre (Column and Row) Headers    
    dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

    // Set Font
    dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 11F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```